# Unable to find out JSP translated files are stored in Google App engine

Tags: spring, maven, jsp, google-app-engine, servlets

Working on webapplication using Spring 3, Maven and deploy code on Google App engine while configure code into workspace it shows error

```
org.apache.jsp.pages.list_jsp could not be resolved
```

Below are the sample code which I am using in web.xml

```
    <servlet>
     <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.pages.list_jsp</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.pages.list_jsp</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
```

When I was created WAR file and delpoyed it on local server i.e. Tomcat then code is working fine but it is not working on Google App engine.

The JSP translated files are stored (in Tomcat) in /work/Catalina/localhost/[your_app_context]/org/apache/jsp/. so with the help same path it was findout the path and work properly but at Google App engine the server is Jetty and it is not recoginized path.

Kinldy suggest me what changes I need to made so the code is working fine.

2) ScreenShot for Production deployment error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3pVH.png)

3) Web.xml configration ScreenShot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKGMk.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Jetty docs](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/configuring-jsp.html), you need to configure the package for precompiled JSPs in your `web.xml`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.jspPackagePrefix</param-name>
    <param-value>org.apache.jsp</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Then try running it locally using [`jetty-maven-plugin`](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-maven-plugin.html). If all goes well, deploy to App Engine.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments it works for me and also added 
<init-param>
         <param-name>keepgenerated</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>

Comment: After applying user shared solutions and I tried to deploy code on local using App engine then it is working fine but when I deployed on Producation server then it caused error. 

Request : POST 20180909t164211-dot-spry-autumn-140509.appspot.com/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs (View request)  
Status : 500 Internal Server Error, Updated Screen shots in Question for error and web.xml configration.

Comment: This sounds unrelated to the JSP issue. No?

Comment: Yes it is not related to Jsp issue but when same code I deployed on Production server "Google App engine" then it cause error as shown above. Please suggest me some solutions for same.

Comment: I would suggest you create another issue for this. Is it something related to Endpoints?